# Uncaught TypeError: items[i].innerText.splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script where I get the inner text of multiple items with the same class name and later work with them

Here is my Code snippet:

```js
function convert() {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("spa");

  for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var multiplier = items[i].innerText.splice(-1)

      var clean = items[i].innerText.replace(splice(-1, -4), '').replace('¥', '')
      console.log(clean, multiplier)
      items[i].innerText = 1;
  }
};
convert()
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="p1">
    <a href="somehref">Unimportant text</a>
  </p>
  <p class="p1">
    <a href="somehref" title="some titel" class="someClass">Not important</a>
  </p>
  <p class="delcar">X</p>
  <p class="p3">
    <span class="spa">¥58.00 x 2</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="p1">
    <a href="somehref">Unimportant text</a>
  </p>
  <p class="p1">
    <a href="somehref" title="some titel" class="someClass">Not important</a>
  </p>
  <p class="delcar">X</p>
  <p class="p3">
    <span class="spa">¥8.00 x 4</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Replace all `splice` with `slice`.

Comment: oh my bad im just blind it seems like

Answer (score 0):

`splice()` is an Array method. You can't use it on Strings.

If you wish to cut out part of the string you need to use `subtring(startIndex, endIndex)` method.

```
let word = 'Hello';
let cut = word.subtring(0, 3); // => 'Hel'
```